# How do I call a function within my main page from another file?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have the following problem:

My Stateful Widget "HomePage" has an Function:

```
void refresh() {
   //not important for now
}
```

But, my whole save and load functions are located in an extra file (save_load.dart)
It's not a class or whatever, just pure functions that I can call from every other file.

```
void loadList(String key) {
   //not important as well
   
   //The following line is what I basically want to achieve
   HomePage.refresh();
}
```

My Problem now is: I want to call the function refresh() after/within the loadList() function. Do you have an idea on how I can achieve this?
Thank you so much!

Comment: are you using any kind of state management? as any will fix your issue.

Comment: no idea, so I guess not

Comment: You could create a utilities class from which you can import it into another file and call functions in there if these are functions that will carry out a simple task. You will have to make it into a class, though, but you can make your methods static so you don't need to instantiate it (i.e. Utils.refresh(), would be inside a class called Utils with a static method called refresh). And you can import it at the top of the file like "import package:your_app/utils.dart";

Comment: @LinusGrosser the official website has a quick guide into dealing with logic like the one you ask: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro

Answer (score 0):

### Summary

The easiest way to achieve what you're looking to do is to use a `GlobalKey<HomePageState>` to reference the `currentState` of your `HomePage` widget and then call the `refresh` method.

### Solution

#### First: Create your Global Key

Create your global key and pass it into your `HomePage` when you create it.

```dart
final GlobalKey<HomePageState> homeKey = GlobalKey<HomePageState>();

...

// In one of your build methods where you're creating your `HomePage` widget.
HomePage(key: homeKey, ...)
```

#### Second: Get The Current State

Next, you'll need to get access to the current state of your `HomePage` widget.

```dart
final homePageState = homeKey.currentState;
```

#### Last: Call Refresh

Finally, you'll want to call the refresh method using the state class you retrieved from the `GlobalKey`.

```dart
// This is how you access it safely
homePageState?.refresh(); // will only call refresh if the homePageState is not null
// OR
homePageState!.refresh(); // will throw if homePageState is null
```